# How to find integral by residue theorem given radius and center points?

Tags: linear-algebra

In general I know how to apply the residue theory to find integral which is to find poles and then resdiue and then:
$2\pi(resdiue, z_k)$ however when they give us a center and radius I get lost how does that change the question.

lets say, there is $\frac{z^2(z+1)}{1+z^2}$ at radius $5$ and region $i$ could you please show me what changes happen when the radius and center change?
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2(1+z)}{1+z^2}$$

Comment: What does "region I" mean?  Did you mean to say the circle is centered at $+i$, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw the complex plane.
2. Draw the poles.
3. Draw your circle.
4. Any poles inside the circle count.  Add up their residues and multiply by $2\pi i$ to get the integral once counterclockwise around the circle.

In this case, your poles are $i$ and $-i$, the roots of $z^2 + 1$.  Your radius is 5 and your center is $i$. So the circle is big enough to enclose both poles. The residue at $z_0$ is $P(z_0)/Q'(z_0) = z_0^2(1+z_0)/(2z_0) = \frac{1}{2}z_0(1+z_0)$.

So $Res(f;i) = i/2 (1+ i/2)$ and $Res(f;-i) = -i/2(1-i/2)$. Add them up and multiply by $2\pi i$.

Comment: I meant center i

Answer (score 0):

The integral is $\frac1{2\pi i}$ times the sum of the residues at the poles enclosed by the contour of integration.  In your example, the poles are at $\pm i$, so you have to check whether they are inside the contour.  In the case where the center is $i$ and the radius is $5$, they both are, so the residues at both poles contribute.  If the radius were $1$, then only the residue at $z=i$ would contribute.